# How to parse a string into a multidimensional array when the separator is optional

Tags: php, string, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a string ($c) that contains a comma-separated list of settings. Some settings are stand-alone, while others require a sub-setting that is separated by an equal sign.

Example:

```
$c = "title,author,tax=taxonomy_A,tax=taxonomy_B,date";
```

I need to parse this string into a multidimensional array ($columns) that outputs like this:

```
$columns = array(
    [0] => array( 'title', '' ),
    [1] => array( 'author', '' ),
    [2] => array( 'tax', 'taxonomy_A' ),
    [3] => array( 'tax', 'taxonomy_B' ),
    [4] => array( 'date', '' )
)
```

I have tried this:

```
        $c = "title,author,tax=taxonomy_A,tax=taxonomy_B,meta=custom_field_key";
    $c = explode( ',', $c );
    $columns = array( explode( '=', $c ) );
```

But that just returns this:

```
$columns = array(
    [0] => array( 'Array' )
)
```

What am I missing here? Should the second explode be replaced with a different function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(explode(',', "title,author,tax=taxonomy_A,tax=taxonomy_B,date") as $item)
        $items[] = array_pad(explode('=', $item), 2, '');
```

Comment: Very elegant...this is the one I will use. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop after the first explode to do the second one:

```
$c = "title,author,tax=taxonomy_A,tax=taxonomy_B,meta=custom_field_key";
$arr = explode( ',', $c );

$result = array();
foreach($arr as $a) {
    array_push($result, explode('=', $a));
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I went with Parahat's solution, but appreciate your help as well!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you don't apply the second explode to each element of the array, but just once to the whole array object. This causes the array to be transformed into the string "Array", which is then run through `explode()` and results in your output.

Instead you could use `array_map()` ([PHP docu](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)):

```
function filterArr( $value ) {
   return explode( '=', $value )
}

$c = "title,author,tax=taxonomy_A,tax=taxonomy_B,meta=custom_field_key";
$c = explode( ',', $c );
$c = array_map( "filterArr", $c );
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I went with Parahat's solution, but appreciate your help as well!